Visualización de gráficos en R
Estoy haciendo unos gráficos en R trabajando con unos datasets, pero al momento de filtrar para trabajar con otros datos el gráfico pierde su forma y no se aprecia bien.
Me pregunto si hay manera de establecer algo en el código para que la gráfica no pierda su forma de acuerdo a los datos o dónde debo modificar para que las líneas no se superpongan y se siga viendo bien sin importar la cantidad de datos que use.
Intenté cambiando los valores tanto en X como en Y y mejoró la separación del gráfico pero todavía se superponen las líneas en el gráfico.
galan_20182 <- filter(SB11_20182, SB11_20182$COLE_CODIGO_ICFES==154294)
galan_20192 <- filter(SB11_20192, SB11_20192$COLE_CODIGO_ICFES==154294)
galan_20202 <- filter(SB11_20202, SB11_20202$COLE_CODIGO_ICFES==154294)
galan_20212 <- filter(SB11_20212, SB11_20212$COLE_CODIGO_ICFES==154294)
galan_20222 <- filter(SB11_20222, SB11_20222$COLE_CODIGO_ICFES==154294)

id_year <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

year <- c(2018,2019,2020,2021,2022)

res_galan_2018 <- data.frame(Lectura = galan_20182$PUNT_LECTURA_CRITICA,
                            Matemáticas = galan_20182$PUNT_MATEMATICAS,
                            Sociales = galan_20182$PUNT_SOCIALES_CIUDADANAS,
                            Naturales = galan_20182$PUNT_C_NATURALES,
                            Inglés = galan_20182$PUNT_INGLES);res_galan_2018



res_galan_2019 <- data.frame(Lectura = galan_20192$PUNT_LECTURA_CRITICA,
                            Matemáticas = galan_20192$PUNT_MATEMATICAS,
                            Sociales = galan_20192$PUNT_SOCIALES_CIUDADANAS,
                            Naturales = galan_20192$PUNT_C_NATURALES,
                            Inglés = galan_20192$PUNT_INGLES);res_galan_2019




res_galan_2020 <- data.frame(Lectura = galan_20202$PUNT_LECTURA_CRITICA,
                            Matemáticas = galan_20202$PUNT_MATEMATICAS,
                            Sociales = galan_20202$PUNT_SOCIALES_CIUDADANAS,
                            Naturales = galan_20202$PUNT_C_NATURALES,
                            Inglés = galan_20202$PUNT_INGLES);res_galan_2020


res_galan_2021 <- data.frame(Lectura = galan_20212$PUNT_LECTURA_CRITICA,
                            Matemáticas = galan_20212$PUNT_MATEMATICAS,
                            Sociales = galan_20212$PUNT_SOCIALES_CIUDADANAS,
                            Naturales = galan_20212$PUNT_C_NATURALES,
                            Inglés = galan_20212$PUNT_INGLES);res_galan_2021

res_galan_2022 <- data.frame(Lectura = galan_20222$PUNT_LECTURA_CRITICA,
                            Matemáticas = galan_20222$PUNT_MATEMATICAS,
                            Sociales = galan_20222$PUNT_SOCIALES_CIUDADANAS,
                            Naturales = galan_20222$PUNT_C_NATURALES,
                            Inglés = galan_20222$PUNT_INGLES);res_galan_2022

etiqueta <- c("Lectura\nCrítica",
              "Matemáticas",
              "Sociales\nCiudadanas",
              "Ciencias\nNaturales",
              "Inglés")

med_res_galan_2022 <- round(apply(res_galan_2022,2,mean));med_res_galan_2022

med_res_galan_2021 <- round(apply(res_galan_2021,2,mean));med_res_galan_2021

med_res_galan_2020 <- round(apply(res_galan_2020,2,mean));med_res_galan_2020

med_res_galan_2019 <- round(apply(res_galan_2019,2,mean));med_res_galan_2019

med_res_galan_2018 <- round(apply(res_galan_2018,2,mean));med_res_galan_2018



acum <- data.frame(
           med_res_galan_2018,
           med_res_galan_2019,
           med_res_galan_2020,
           med_res_galan_2021,
           med_res_galan_2022)
acum
acum[1,]

plot(id_year, acum[1,], type = "l", lwd=2, xlim = c(0,6),
     ylim = c(40,80), axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "")



id_col <- c("black","red","blue","green","orange")

for(i in 1:4){
  lines(id_year,acum[i+1,],col=id_col[i+1],lwd=2)
}

id_col2 <- c("black","red","blue","green","orange")

for(i in 1:5){
  points(id_year,acum[i,], pch=15, col=id_col2[i])  
}

axis(1,pos = 40,lwd = 2,at=c(1:5),labels = c(year),font = 2)

axis(2,pos = 0,at=seq(40,55,by=5),lwd = 2,font = 2,las=2)

arrows(0,40,6,40,length = 0.15,angle = 15,lwd = 2)
arrows(0,40,0,60,length = 0.15,angle = 15,lwd = 2)

title(main = "Resultados Prueba Saber 11 Año 2018-2022")
title(main = "Instituto José Antonio Galán",line = 0.5)
title(xlab = "Años",font.lab=2)
title(ylab = "Puntajes",font.lab=2,line = 1)

legend("top",lty = 1,col = id_col2,lwd = 2,pch = 15,
       legend = c("Lectura",
                  "Matemáticas",
                  "Sociales",
                  "Naturales",
                  "Inglés"),
       horiz = T, 
       bty = "l",bg="lightblue",text.font = 2,
       text.col = id_col2)

text(id_year,acum[1,],pos = 3,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[1,])
text(1,acum[2,1],pos = 3,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[2,1],
     col="red")

text(2,acum[2,2],pos = 2,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[2,2],
     col="red")

text(3,acum[2,3],pos = 3,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[2,3],
     col="red")

text(4,acum[2,4],pos = 3,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[2,4],
     col="red")

text(5,acum[2,5],pos = 4,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[2,5],
     col="red")

text(id_year[-3],acum[3,-3],pos = 3,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[3,-3],
     col="blue")

text(id_year[3],acum[3,3],pos = 1,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[3,3],
     col="blue")

text(id_year[1],acum[4,1],pos = 2,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[4,1],
     col="green")

text(id_year[5],acum[4,5],pos = 3,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[4,5],
     col="green")

text(id_year[3],acum[4,3],pos = 1,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[4,3],
     col="green")

text(id_year[4],acum[4,4],pos = 3,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[4,4],
     col="green")

text(id_year,acum[5,],pos = 1,font = 2,cex = 0.8,labels = acum[5,],
     col="orange")




Hay algo extraño, usaste ylim = c(40,80) pero veo que el gráfico tiene un límite 40 a 55, checkea eso. Si quieres lograr que el gráfico mantenga siempre las mismas características, el primer plot es el clave. Eso sí está muy largo tu código, puedes parametrizar muchas de las cosas q tienes y achicar tu código creando funciones para ello. Sin datos reproducibles, no podría elaborar una respuesta por tiempo
